# Batch file wont continue after call up a powershell script

Tags: windows, batch-file, powershell

I have a situation. I'm installing network printer on remote desktops using a batch file that calls up a Powershell script, but after printer is installed on the remote desktop, Powershell returns nothing - so my batch file wont be able to continue...I must manually hit ENTER twice to make it `echo DONE` and run the rest of the scripts. Any idea why?

```
@echo off

Copy /Y "\\AddPrinter\AddPrinter.ps1" "C:\scripts" 

powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "C:\scripts\AddPrinter.ps1" 

Echo DONE

Del /F /Q "C:\ntfs3\scripts\AddPrinter.ps1"
```

This is my powershell script, I even put a `exit` in the end of script, but powershell on remote pc just wont exit.....so it will not return to batch

```
$PrinterPath = "\\server-01\Printer0101"
$net = new-Object -com WScript.Network
$net.AddWindowsPrinterConnection($PrinterPath)
exit
```

BTW, I m using psexec to call up this batch file with a txt file containing all pc names.

```
psexec @%1 -u admin -p xxxxxx -c -f "C:\AAA\AddPrinter.bat"
```

I did some research, some one said need to use `call` with `%1 > null` to make Powershell return to batch. But it does not work either.

```
Call powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "C:\scripts\AddPrinter.ps1"  %1 > null
```

I could only use batch command to install printer, but after installation, the new printer always setup as a default printer. but if use powershell to install it, it wont change default printer on remote desktop.

```
rundll32 printui.dll PrintUIEntry /ga /n\\server-01\printer0101
```

Hint please.

Comment: Maybe your powershell script takes time to finish its execution. Can you paste the contents of the powershell file?

Comment: I pasted powershell script, it will only take 15 seconds to finish.

Comment: If you run the PowerShell script manually from a PowerShell prompt, does it prompt for input?

Comment: NO, it just run and finish. no prompt at all

Comment: It works with or without `Call` in the batch file for me. Maybe add the `-NoProfile` switch to your powershell.exe line? What account are you running this under?

Comment: I run as domain admin, I dont think i need -NoProfile swtich, cuz i use psexec connect to remote pc as admin.

Answer (score 2):

I have regularly seen problems calling PowerShell through `psexec.exe`. I would recommend ditching psexec.exe and configuring PowerShell Remoting instead. Then, you can deploy your script using the `Invoke-Command` command.

Comment: I agree with you. the thing i m not allowed to open PSRemoting....too risky said by upper level.....

Answer (score 0):

I could also suggest for DOS like commands to use `invoke-expression`. PowerShell will process the command that you are passing as it is. The great is that you will be able to pass also variables